# Impala convert string to timestamp in format 'Fri Mar 02 00:00:00 GMT 2018'

Tags: string, timestamp, impala

I want to convert a string field to timestamp with Impala.
I tried using this expression which works fine in Hive:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Fri Mar 02 00:00:00 GMT 2018','EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy')) AS Date_Call_Year;
```

but I get the error "Bad date/time conversion format: EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy". What is wrong with this format?